# Slide UISlider programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a `UISLider` with certain values assigned to its each step. I'm getting those values from another VC and if the value is greater than the beginning of the slider, let's say the value is 50 out of 100 possible, I want to move the handle of the slider to represent that value, apparently to the middle and so on.

How do you do this easy task in iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uh.. have you tried calling `setValue:animated`?

Or reading the docs?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: No sweat, also please be sure to accept one of the answers provided.

Answer (score 3):

By default `UISlider` value should be between 0 and 1 (unless you've set `minimumValue` & `maximumValue`)

```
[yourSlider setValue:0.5 animated:YES];
```

See `UISlider` documentation for more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: UISlider value does not have to be between 0 and 1. You can set the min and max using minimumValue and maximumValue.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked that.  Updated the answer.